# Getting location by few ways in Timer

Tags: java, android, syntax, timer, syntax-error

Hello I'm creating tracking app and I want to quickly get the location. But this app should be friendly for people. It should works like that:

1. I turn on GPS and i want to get location by it
2. If it takes more that 5 seconds I try get location by network provider
3. If it takes more that 5 seconds i try to get location by wifi
4. if it takes more I do something else.

I already have this functions! How to do that they work one after another (If one wokrs more than 5 sec we move to another one).

So I'm thinking that I must use some kind of timer, but here I got a problem if I put code like this

```
    Timer timer2 = new Timer(); 
    TimerTask testing = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() { 
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });


        }
    }; timer2.schedule(testing, 1000); ***
*** here syntax errors
```

not inside `onCreate` I have syntax errors (and I want to do that after pushing the button). However how should looks this timer for 3 methods following next by next ?

Answer (score 0):

depending on the OS that you are devlopping for, I would recommend you to make use of the OS specific methods available for retrieving location.

In case of Android for example there is a service available that makes is quite easy for you to retrieve the location in an user friendly manner:

Please check this: https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

This allows you to create location requests, depending on your situation you can define the request with a certain priority. For example: in case city precision is enough in your situation, you can define it and the framework might decide to only use the currently available WIFI to get the location (and not startup the GPS).

Comment: But question wasn't for it  I have wrote this functions. So we have 3 functions GpsLocation(); / WifiLocation / GsmLocation(); but i want that they should work  one after another (If first don't get location in 5 sec we move to another) and the question is how wrote something like that I probably know that it should be a timer.